# react installation not progressing further

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, web-frontend, web-frameworks

I've installed `npx create-react-app project` and `npm init react-app project` various times but the installation gets stuck at a certain point and does not proceed further.

This is the installation which is not proceeding further.

```bash
Need to install the following packages:
  create-react-app@5.0.1
Ok to proceed? (y) Y
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

Creating a new React app in F:\Nimra's\MY LOCKUP\IT WORK\React\reactjs.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

[#########.........] | reify:fsevents: sill reify mark deleted [
```

Answer (score 2):

The apostrophe in the path is the issue.  Either rename the folder called `Nimra's` to remove the apostrophe, or move to a different folder.

Something in the install process is reading the `'` as the beginning or end of a string, which is causing the installation to stall/crash.

It may also make your life easier later to remove the spaces from your path (`MY LOCKUP` & `IT WORK`).  In general, avoid special characters in file & folder names, whenever possible.