# React Native project initialisation stuck at installing on command line

Tags: windows, react-native, npx, installation-package

I began to create my first react native project and followed the documentation given on the official website but now the installation is stuck at this in CMD and it won't go any further. Any ideas what could be the issue?

[Stuck at installing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90mrG.jpg)
I tried to cancel the installation but doesn't work. It gets stuck again.

Comment: any special characters in your path?  looks very similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76559525/react-installation-not-progressing-further/76559631#76559631